# ubuntu selenium python - firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file

Tags: python, linux, firefox, ubuntu, selenium

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The error I'm getting from Selenium is:

"Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox\nBuild info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'\nSystem info: host: 'ip-10-29-152-181', ip: '10.29.152.181', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-54-virtual', java.version: '1.6.0_34'\nDriver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver"

Firefox is installed as so -

[image]

Notice the directory is /usr/lib/firefox

That directory is added to the $PATH
[image]

I get this error from Selenium -
[image]

Notice it's looking for /usr/bin/firefox

Here's what the files in that directory look like-
[image]

Any help?
I ran

```
source .bashrc
```

and also rebooted the box. Still nothing.

Could it have something to do with the symlink I'm using in /usr/bin/firefox ?

Comment: Shouldn the symlink be `firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox` and no `.sh`

Comment: strange. i tried both
`/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` and
`/usr/lib/firefox`

getting the same error